# Unable to connect to IP-camera

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, camera

I have a Sinocam IP-camera which was connected to a Huawei b593 4g router, until a supposed computer engineer fiddled with the cameras settings and rendered it unusable.
The camera ships with a static ip address of 192.168.1.100, but does not respond to pings on that address any more.

The camera is connected to the router with an ethernet cable, I have tried several cables to exclude cable problems.

After sending an email to the (chinese) producer of the camera asking them for help, I got a reply that said (quote):

> Please change your PC with fix IP address and add 192.168.5.xxx, 192.168.1.xxx

I think they mean that I should put a static ip address on my computer and then I should be able to connect to the camera. I have tried but it does not work.

I have tried `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` and `nmap -A -T4 192.168.1.*`  but the camera does not seem to be listed.

How can I troubleshoot this?

---

There is no reset button on the camera. The email from the producer tries to explain how to reset it by using telnet.

I tried the camera on a different router, but everything still behaves the same. The camera does not show up on any of the routers 'connected devices' page.

I tried to connect to the camera by setting a static ip on my laptop and connecting them directly with an ethernet cable, but I got no response from the cameras static ip address or from nmap.

I tried again to connect to the camera, but it did not work. What I tried:

1. set my ip to static 192.168.1.14
2. reboot
3. connect camera directly to computer with ethernet cable
4. execute `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0-255` -> only my computers address showed up
5. execute `telnet 192.168.1.100` -> 'could not connect'

I tried once more to connect the camera directly to my laptop, but it did not work. Here's what I did:

1. Purchased a twisted network cable and connected my laptop and camera with it
2. Set my laptops static ip to 192.168.1.13, I also tried 192.168.5.13
3. Performed nmap, ping and telnet commands in cmd to no avail.

I'm at a loss here. Maybe the camera is just broken.

Comment: What is your PC's ip Address, ie, what address does your router give your PC?

Comment: Can you reset the device? A little button at the back?

Comment: There is no reset button on the device. @E. Carter my PC's ip address is 192.168.1.4

Comment: Do you know what settings were changed? If not, you may have to connect the camera directly to a PC running something like `tcpdump` to try to infer its settings based on what it sends out.

Comment: @david no I do not know what settings were changed. I have tried connecting it directly with my pc, but I was unable to communicate with the camera. I will try again later today.

Comment: Regarding Update 4: last step, you tried to telnet your own PC... have you tried putting a 192.168.5.x IP on your PC, then nmap for that subnet (192.168.5.0/24) with the camera connected to see if the "computer engineer" has only changed the camera subnet?

Another thing: if you connect the PC directly to the camera, be sure to have a cross-over cable.  Straight cable will probably not work unless your ethernet port support AUTO-MDIX (which even if it does, is often barely working)

Comment: @remi wops that was a typo in the update. I  set my computers address to 192.168.1.14 (see edit) . I did not try with 192.168.5.x, I will try that later, as well as buying a twisted cable.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any button on the device the manual has to provide reset procedure. It is just how it is done, it is a standard.

Comment: As mentioned before there is not a reset button on the camera. There is no manual available either.

Comment: @hansn Please provide exact model name.

Comment: I don't have it, but I will see if I can find it somewhere.

Comment: It's SinoCam h . 264

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem when wi-fi IP address was set to be the same as the wired IP address.  I resolved it by turning the wi-fi radio on the router off and by connecting both computer and the camera by ethernet wires.  I was able to access camera's setup page that way and change the wi-fi IP address.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download the free "Network scanner" tool from Softperfect. It shows you a list of all connected devices and their IP addresses.Then attach the router only to you PC with an ethernet cable and type the IP into your browser. You should then arrive at the router's internal home page.
Hope my answer can help you!